# Meaning of ineternal?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I read this sentence: "By what acts can I escape a sorrowful lot in this unstable **ineternal** Samsâra, which is full of misery?" This is from Jaina Sutras, which was translated in 1895.

By context I think it is a synonym of noneternal / not eternal. But I have doubts and Google does not have any good results on this.

Comment: This is not a standard English word; the translator must have invented it!

Comment: Thank you. I know the translator was a native German speaker.

Comment: The rules of English permit the attachment of prefixes and suffixes to create nonce words.